# Input numbers by keyboard into array but only 1 line

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any way to enter numbers (seperated by spaces) on a single line into an array ? I mean, I used to write like this:

> First, I entered sizeofarray. Then, I used [for] loop to enter each number into each element. In this method, I had to press enter for each time

So what I want is:

> First, enter sizeofarray. Then, on a single line, enter all numbers for all elements, each of it seperated by a space
>
> Ex: 7, enter
>
> 1 5 35 26 5 69 8, enter

So that all numbers are stored into elements dedicated.

I know my English is not good and I'm not a good coder. So please explain it easy. Thanks :D

Comment: Why not let the program count the numbers instead of requiring the user to count them first?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why everyone is trying to do it in String way..
it's simple that C++ std::cin can get it so easy

```
int main (){  
int a[1000],sizeOfA;
cin>>sizeOfA;
for (int i=0;i<sizeOfA;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
```

Comment: Better add a last call to `.ignore` or input of line to empty the input buffer, ready for e.g. subsequent input of a `char`.

Comment: i think it's only needed when you are using strings otherwise it won't cause any problem.

Comment: Try input of a `char` after that.

Comment: I've just tried it using Geany/C++11 it worked well..
maybe it effects `C` only not `C++`

Comment: Sorry, example at (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/527ebca319d7c64b). Stack Overflow didn't like the ">" at the end in previous comment :(. When you add option `-D CLEAN` to the compiler invocation you get X as input instead of a linefeed, which is  how it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to enter all numbers in a single line, then it is completely unnecessary to begin by entering the number of numbers that will follow.

You are going to need to read the entire line into a string, (`char[]`) and then parse that string to find substrings separated by spaces, and then you are going to need to parse each substring into a number.

Precisely how to do this, we won't tell, because stackoverflow is not about having others do your homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I will look into it :D

Answer (score 2):

Read in the input as a string, then split by spaces to get the individual numbers:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int* nums;
    int size;
    cout << "Enter size of array";
    cin >> size;
    nums = new int[size];
    string input;
    cout << "Enter numbers, separated by single space:\n";
    getline(cin, input);
    istringstream iss(input);
    string s;

    int i = 0;
    while (getline(iss, s, ' ') && i < size) {
        int num = atoi(s.c_str());
        nums[i] = num;
        printf("%d\n", num);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as I was saying that we won't tell him precisely how to do this, being under the (apparently wrong) impression that stackoverflow is not about having others do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

the most optimal and safe way is use containers, iterators and streams. If 'istream_iterator ' extract from the stream value other than 'int', it will be equal to 'end', so reading from the stream being to the first non-int, or until the end

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    size_t size = 0;
    cin >> size;
    cin.ignore();

    string buffer;
    getline(cin, buffer);

    stringstream ss(buffer);
    istream_iterator<int> iter(ss);
    istream_iterator<int> end;

    vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size && iter != end; ++i, ++iter)
    {
        vec.push_back(*iter);
    }
}
```